# Probability Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose we have two possible states of some entity, $A$, and $B$. Say, the probability that the initial state is $A$ is $p_i$ and the probability that the initial state is $B$ is $1-p_i$

After the system has been initialized, it behaves as a markov chain with:
$$P(A \to A) = p_{11}$$ $$P(A \to B) = 1- p_{11}$$ $$P(B \to B) = p_{22}$$ $$P( B \to A) = 1-p_{22}.$$

Now suppose your system is initialized, and you are not able to observe the initial state or the second state. If you observe the third state to be $B$, what is the probability that  the initial state was $A$?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it not true that the observation of the third state has no effect on the initialization probabilities? And thus the answers is simply $p_i$?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's true. As an extreme example, suppose that $P(A \to B) = P(B \to A) = 0$, and that $P(A \to A) = P(B \to B) = 1$. If you observe that the state in time 3 is $B$, the probability the initial state was $A$ is 0.

One way to compute the probability you're looking for is to tweak Daniel's approach by also conditioning on $X_2$, e.g.,

\begin{align*}
 P(X_3 = B \,|\, X_1 = A) &= P(X_3 = B \,|\, X_2 = A, X_1 = A)P(X_2 = A \,|\, X_1 = A) \\ 
& \qquad + P(X_3 = B \,|\, X_2 = B, X_1 = A)P(X_2 = B \,|\, X_1 = A)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your intuition is correct. To show this, write $X_i \in \{A,B\}$ to be the observations at state $i$. Then by Bayes,
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 = A \mid X_3 = B) &= \frac{P(X_3 = B \mid X_1 = A)P(X_1 = A)}{P(X_3 = B)}\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \frac{P(X_3 = B)P(X_1 = A)}{P(X_3 = B)}\\
&= P(X_1 = A)
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ follows from the fact that $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov Chain.